# Split string and keep delimiter in javascript plus conditions

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I need a method in javascript to split a string by the delimiter `FF`, which will almost always be followed by another **any** of this `(F0,F1,FA,FB,FC,FD,FE)` or in some minor cases by `00` or `01`. The final array will need to look like this:

```
var string = 'FFFC18FFFC20FFFC23FFFC27';
'FFFC18FFFC20FFFC23FFFC27'
var array = string.split(regex);
['FFFC18','FFFC20','FFFC23','FFFC27']
```

Eventually, an element could have less than 8 characters, like in this example:

```
var string = 'FFFA2701FFF0FFFA1801FFF0';
'FFFA2701FFF0FFFA1801FFF0'
var array = string.split(regex);
['FFFA2701','FFF0','FFFA1801','FFF0']
```

Finally, this case could also happen (a case in which the delimited `FF` could be followd by `00` or `01` too):

```
var string = 'FF00FFF0FF001801FFF0';
'FF00FFF0FF001801FFF0'
var array = string.split(regex);
['FF01','FFF0','FF001801','FFF0']
```

Thanks in advance.

What I tried and almost worked to me is just splitting by 'FF' and trying to add again the FF at the beggining of each element, but couldn't do it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for an implementation of a requirement, rather than asking for help with a specific issue encountered when implementing the requirement.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't undertand what you exactly meant. My issue is that I can't split a string keeping the delimiter, how should I format the question so that it shouldn't be off-topic?

Comment: @ederollora Basically, you're asking us to *"send you t3h codez"*. You should have tried something yourself and asked for help with your implementation

Comment: Sorry for not specifying what I tried but If I came here to ask is because my case is so specific that I couldn't solve it myself. I have been trying the last hours, reading how regex works but I simply couldn't . By the way don't know what t3h codez means

Comment: I've already looked for 'split string by regex and keep delimiter'-like questions but I couldn't work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your pattern, like this:

```
/(?=FF(?:F[01A-E]|0[01]))/
```

A lookahead will match the position in the string which is immediately followed by the given pattern, but that matching substring will not be consumed as part of the match.

For example:

```
'FFFC18FFFC20FFFC23FFFC27'.split(/(?=FF(?:F[01A-E]|0[01]))/)
["FFFC18", "FFFC20", "FFFC23", "FFFC27"]

'FFFA2701FFF0FFFA1801FFF0'.split(/(?=FF(?:F[01A-E]|0[01]))/)
["FFFA2701", "FFF0", "FFFA1801", "FFF0"]

'FF00FFF0FF001801FFF0'.split(/(?=FF(?:F[01A-E]|0[01]))/)
["FF00", "FFF0", "FF001801", "FFF0"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. That worked. I've been for such a long time trying to look for the solution that I came here and ask. A couple of users have tried to close it, I don't exactly know what I made wrong but as I said if I came here is because I was desperate. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Glad I could help. Basically, you showed some sample inputs and what you want the outputs to be, which is very important, but you neglected to show how you attempted to solve it yourself. The regex tag is *full* of questions like 'I want to match X' that show no effort or understanding of regular expressions. If you had provided even a short snippet of code from your own attempt, you probably would've gotten a better reaction. In any case, keep that in mind the next time you ask a question :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the exlanation. To be true I didn't get a such a good attempt that I thought it would be good to place here but I'll try to improve the next time. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: One last question, do you know why for this example `FF00FFF0FFF01801FFF0` I get this output? `[FF00,FFF0,F,FF01801,FFF0]` Thank you for you time! And sorry to bother but I didn0t figure out the reason

Comment: Well it breaks at `FFF0` because that's a valid position to break according to your rules, but then it also breaks at `FF01`, because that too is a valid position to break. One of the consequences of using a lookahead like this is that you can have overlaping matches.

Comment: Might be able to fix that by adding a `(?<!F)` after the lookahead. Sort of inhibit's staggering. `(?=FF(?:F[01A-E]|0[01]))(?<!F)` prints `FF00 FFF0 FFF01801 FFF0` though I'm sure something might break it.